# Loop through list, set variable

Tags: loops, batch-file

I'm trying to make a loop that goes through a file with filenames on each line, set the first filename as a variable and execute the rest if the script. Then take the second line and do the same. 
etc. etc.
The problem is that it only does the first line of filenames.txt

```
@echo off

for /F "tokens=*" %%G in (filenames.txt) do (
set filename=%%G
script
script
script
)
pause
```

It has be a batch file.
The whole script:

```
@ECHO OFF
for /F "tokens=*" %%G in (filenames.txt) do (
SET FileName=%%G
SET Word1="ts_confirmImplicitSAMM.gram"
SET Word2="SWIrcnd"
for /f "tokens=3" %%f in ('find /c /i %Word1% %FileName%') do set PairsToShow=%%f
SET /a Lines1=0, Lines2=0
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN ('findstr "%Word1%" "%FileName%"') DO (
SET "str=%%a"
SET /a Lines1+=1
SETLOCAL enabledelayedexpansion
SET "$1!Lines1!=!str!"
FOR /f "tokens=1*delims==" %%b IN ('set "$1"') DO (IF "!"=="" endlocal)&SET "%%b=%%c"
)
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN ('findstr "%Word2%" "%FileName%"') DO (
SET "str=%%a"
SET /a Lines2+=1
SETLOCAL enabledelayedexpansion
SET "$2!Lines2!=!str!"
FOR /f "tokens=1*delims==" %%b IN ('set "$2"') DO (IF "!"=="" endlocal)&SET "%%b=%%c"
)
SET /a Lines=Lines1+Lines2
ECHO(%Lines% lines read from %FileName%.
IF %Lines1% leq %Lines2% (SET /a MaxPairs=Lines1) ELSE SET /a MaxPairs=Lines2
IF %PairsToShow% gtr %MaxPairs% (
ECHO only text for %MaxPairs% pairs NOT %PairsToShow% :/
GOTO :END
)
(FOR /l %%a IN (1,1,%PairsToShow%) DO (
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
CALL SET "Line1=%%$1%%a%%"
CALL SET "Line2=%%$2%%a%%"
<NUL SET /p "=!Line1!"
ECHO !Line2!
ENDLOCAL
))>> result1.txt
ENDLOCAL
TYPE result1.txt| FINDSTR /V EVNT=SWIgrld >> result.txt
DEL result1.txt

PAUSE
)
```

Comment: very unclear question ...

Comment: Obviously you have the loop, so what is the question?

Comment: You can not use %%G outside the LOOP construct.  Your line --->   )  %%G

Comment: because it doesn't work

Comment: it only does the first line of filenames.txt

Comment: You should edit your code to show the problem. btw the solution is found with `setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion`

Comment: how can i do that? And thanks i'm going to look in to that!

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the rest of your script... you probably need to do 1 of 2 things:

1. Use SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION (as 2nd line of your script) and then reference the variable filename as !filename! instead of %filename% to use the run-time value instead of the load-time value.  But that could cause other problems, depending on what goes on in "script".
2. Just use %%G instead of filename

Comment: But when am I supposed to use !filename! if I should us %G% instead?